# How to decode access token and get username and email in java?

Tags: java, encryption, jwt, base64, keycloak

How can I get the name and email from a token .

Structure of the token using jwt.io
http://prntscr.com/yzyf2b

Any help is appreciated.

Update full solution with the help of below posts so credits to them .

```
            String jwtToken = token;
            System.out.println("------------ Decode JWT ------------");
            String[] split_string = jwtToken.split("\\.");
            String base64EncodedHeader = split_string[0];
            String base64EncodedBody = split_string[1];
            String base64EncodedSignature = split_string[2];

            System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~ JWT Header ~~~~~~~");
            Base64 base64Url = new Base64(true);
            String header = new String(base64Url.decode(base64EncodedHeader));
            System.out.println("JWT Header : " + header);

            System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~ JWT Body ~~~~~~~");
            String body = new String(base64Url.decode(base64EncodedBody));
            System.out.println("JWT Body : " + body);

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(body);
            System.out.println(jsonObject.get("email"));
            System.out.println(jsonObject.get("name"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A JWToken has the following structure `Header.Body.Signature`. Hence, first you should split the token into three parts, namely `Header`, `Body` and `Signature`.

For that you can use

```
String[] token_part = jwtToken.split("\\.");
```

then apply what you already have done but for the `token_part[1]` (*i.e.,* the payload or Body), namely:

```
sun.misc.BASE64Decoder decoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();
String a = new String(decoder.decodeBuffer(token_part[1]));
```

For the decoding part, alternatively, you can try [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916912/how-to-decode-jwt-header-and-body-in-java-using-apache-commons-codec).

After that you can use the [org.json.JSONObject](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-can-we-convert-a-json-string-to-a-json-object-in-java) to parse the JSON. An example:

```
public class Token {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String token = "{\"name\":\"john doe\", \"email\": \"john@mail.com\"}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(token);
        System.out.println(jsonObject.get("email"));
        System.out.println(jsonObject.get("name"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
john@mail.com
john doe
```

Full Example:

```
    String jwtToken = token;
    System.out.println("------------ Decode JWT ------------");
    String[] split_string = jwtToken.split("\\.");
    String base64EncodedHeader = split_string[0];
    String base64EncodedBody = split_string[1];
    String base64EncodedSignature = split_string[2];

    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~ JWT Header ~~~~~~~");
    Base64 base64Url = new Base64(true);
    String header = new String(base64Url.decode(base64EncodedHeader));
    System.out.println("JWT Header : " + header);

    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~ JWT Body ~~~~~~~");
    String body = new String(base64Url.decode(base64EncodedBody));
    System.out.println("JWT Body : " + body);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(body);
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("email"));
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("name"));
```